# difference between two regular expressions: [abc]+ and ([abc])+

Tags: python, regex

```
In [29]: re.findall("([abc])+","abc")
Out[29]: ['c']

In [30]: re.findall("[abc]+","abc")
Out[30]: ['abc']
```

Confused by the grouped one. How does it make difference?

Comment: `re.findall` throws a wrench into the analysis since `re.findall("[abc]+","abc")` captures anyway without the parenthesis (shows the complete match then...) Try `re.search(r'([abc])+', 'abc').group(1)` and `re.search(r'([abc]+)', 'abc').group(1)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two things that need to be explained here: the behavior of quantified groups, and the design of the `findall()` method.

In your first example, `[abc]` matches the `a`, which is captured in group #1.  Then it matches `b` and captures it in group #1, overwriting the `a`.  Then again with the `c`, and that's what's left in group #1 at the end of the match.

But it *does* match the whole string.  If you were using `search()` or `finditer()`, you would be able to look at the MatchObject and see that `group(0)` contains `abc` and `group(1)` contains `c`.  But `findall()` returns strings, not MatchObjects.  If there are no groups, it returns a list of the overall matches;  if there are groups, the list contains all the captures, but *not* the overall match.

So both of your regexes are matching the whole string, but the first one is also capturing and discarding each character individually (which is kinda pointless).  It's only the unexpected behavior of `findall()` that makes it look like you're getting different results.

Answer (score 7):

In the first example you have a repeated captured group which only capture the last iteration. Here `c`.

```
([abc])+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/xlTVLUk_iJOLaG-r)

In the second example you are matching a single character in the list one and unlimited times.

```
[abc]+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/fsSAzDJ5tnWyfa-W)

Answer (score 3):

Here's the way I would think about it.  `([abc])+` is attempting to repeat a captured group.  When you use "+" after the capture group, it doesn't mean you are going to get two captured groups.  What ends up happening, at least for Python's regex and most implementations, is that the "+" forces iteration until the capture group only contains the last match.

If you want to capture a repeated expression, you need to reverse the ordering of "(...)" and "+", e.g. instead of `([abc])+` use `([abc]+)`.

Answer (score 1):

input "abc"

```
[abc]
```

match a single character => "a"

```
[abc]+
```

**+** Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible => "abc"

```
([abc])
```

Capturing group ([abc]) => "a"

```
([abc])+
```

**+** A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration => "c"

Answer (score -3):

Grouping just gives different preference.

`([abc])+` => Find one from selection. Can match one or more. It finds one and all conditions are met as the + means 1 or more. This breaks up the regex into two stages.

While the ungrouped one is treated as a whole.

Comment: This explanation is completely wrong. There is no short-circuiting involved. If this explanation were correct, the first `findall` would have returned `['a']` instead of `['c']`.

Comment: Short-circuts may be the wrong term. all conditions are met. - changed language to reflect

Comment: No, it's not just "short-circuit" being the wrong term. The mechanism at work does not work the way you describe. As another example, `^([abc])+$` doesn't give `'abc'` either; [it still gives `['c']`](http://ideone.com/Mj9Wh2).