# Extract the last few words in a sentence using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regex to extract the last few words from a sentence. However, I can't seem to make it work.

```
var str = "Tell me about robin hood";
const TELL_ME_ABOUT_REGEX = /^Tell me about (\w+\s*)*/
if( str.match(TELL_ME_ABOUT_REGEX) ){
    var matches = TELL_ME_ABOUT_REGEX.exec( str );
    console.log( "user wants to know about ",matches);
}
```

I am trying to get the word "robin hood". But I only end up with "hood".

```
[ 'Tell me about robin hood',
  'hood',
  index: 0,
  input: 'Tell me about robin hood' ]
```

What do I change in my regex?

Comment: Try this `Tell me about ([\w\s]+)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a correct regex:

```
^Tell me about ((?:\w+\s*)*)
```

Compare to your original one which is

```
^Tell me about (\w+\s*)*
```

That's so closed. The point is you should use the non-capturing group for an inner bracket and capturing group for an outer bracket.

Note that `(\w+\s*)*` from your regex, it might captures `robin` to `\1` at the first time and then overwrites `hood` to `\1`. So, now you might understand that regex engine will work in this way.

Answer (score 3):

Why you need regex for this? You can do it without regex like it

```
var str = "Tell me about robin hood";
var str = str.split(" ").splice(3).join(" ");
alert(str);
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNvrYz

**Edit : Regex Solution**

```
var str = "Tell me about robin hood";

var match =  str.match(/^Tell me about (.*)/i);
var textInDe = match[1]; 
alert(textInDe);
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BKoerY

Comment: hahah !! yeah  ! there's that ! but I am learning regex so... :)

Comment: its always good to learn... I have added regex solution for you

Answer (score 2):

The problem with `/^Tell me about (\w+\s*)*/` is that are multiples matches for `"Tell me about robin hood"`, i.e., `robin` is a possible match, as well `robin\s` and so forth. The repetition characters may confuse you sometimes, but when you think on all match possibilities, it can be clearer.
For matching all that came after `Tell me about` you can simply get it all at once, with only one possible match: `(.*)`.

[Regex demo](http://rubular.com/r/wcIgDChev7)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Tell me about ([\w\s]+)
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rM9fS7/1)

`(\w+\s*)*` will capture 'robin' then 'hood' but only keep the last iteration => 'hood'

Comment: Why does it only keep the last iteration? :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35677905/difference-between-two-regular-expressions-abc-and-abc/35677940#35677940

Comment: A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data. So `((\w+\s*)*)` will capture 'robin hood' too.